# Having input type submit display something other than their value

Tags: html, input

```
<input type = 'submit' value = '1'>
```

^---Instead of the input type displaying '1', I would like for it to display 'first page'. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. Set the value to "First Page"

Comment: value = ''first page"?

Comment: I think what he wants is for it display something different from what it sends to the server.[

Comment: @Barmar God. I swear, what's with people these day...

Comment: @frosty woops didn't read correctly the title.

Comment: @YounesMgharfaoui Did you down vote?

Comment: @forsty Nope I didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `<input type="submit">` or `<input type="button">`, it's not possible to separate the value that's sent from the label on the button. If you want to do that, you need to use `<button>`.

```
<button type="submit" value="1">First Page</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of the button tag for this purpose is a new information for me and thanks for sharing that. 
Depending on your requirement you can use a hidden filed to hold your value which gets submitted when the form is submitted.

if you want to use it with JS then you can use another attribute to hold the value such as "title" or a custom one, eg:cusval

If your intention is to see if the particular submit button was click at the server side then you can check if the variable is available in the post data.

PHP eg:  if( isset($_POST['submitbtn']) )

Answer (score -1):

Just value="First Page". value will display whatever you want. It may be string or int.

Comment: This will also change what's sent to the server, not just what's displayed.